# Слэш в параметре URL

Tags: mod_rewrite, php

Добрый день! У меня в проекте используется mod_rewrite, когда у меня URL имеет вид:

```
http://test.ru/tag/android
```

где **android** - нужный мне тег. В этом случае все работает прекрасно. Как решить проблему, если мой тег будет иметь вид: ***AC/DC***, тогда URL будет выглядеть:

```
http://test.ru/tag/AC/DC
```

и следовательно скрипт будет обрабатывать только **AC**
пропуская через **urlencode()**, слэш "/" преобразуется в "**%2F**" и тогда сервер выдает ***404 ошибку***!
Подскажите, как быть??

Спасибо

Comment: AC|DC

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```
http://test.ru/tag/AC\/DC
```

Хотя, не уверен, что поможет..

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогает..

Answer (score 0):

Обычно слеши в адресной строке используются для указания иерархических путей, поэтому если вам нужно указать тег вида: `AC/DC`, то слеш, стоящий посередине, следует заменить на другой символ, или код: "`%2F`".

Comment: а без замены на другой символ? про код "%2F" я писал в посте..

Comment: urldecode() :-)

Comment: не, мне нужно закодировать

Comment: это не правильный подход вообщето, в данном случае / эправляющий символ получается... не понял в чем проблема использовать %2F... 404? может у вас rewriteRule неправильно написано? в любом случае надо туда смотреть, в .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

в данном случае / управляющий символ получается -- это неправильно... не понял в чем проблема использовать %2F... 404? может у вас rewriteRule неправильно написано? в любом случае надо туда смотреть, в .htaccess скорее всего правило надо переписать... что вы дальше с полученным тегом делаете также не понятно, может и в этом проблема тоже.